# Using LIKE in mysql to get list for autocomplete

Tags: php, mysql

I am using LIKE clause to get the list for autocomplete. When I use

```
name LIKE '%value%'
```

it is giving me list of names that contains "value" in it, but it not showing this list correctly  for eg. when give value "san" and I have "sanclose" in table but it is not showing this value in result. So I thought may be I should remove % wildcard from front. So After Removing front % wildcard

```
name LIKE 'value%'
```

now it is not giving me any results. My column have full-text search index also.

Please suggestion am I missing something or there is other better ways to get better results?

Thanks in advance.

This is my full sql that I am trying

```
SELECT z.zone_id, CONCAT(z.name,',',c.name) as zone FROM zone z LEFT JOIN country c ON z.country_id = c.country_id WHERE z.name LIKE 'span%'
```

Comment: Why are you using LIKE when you could use a fulltext search?

Comment: What you have should work (although a leading wild card in a LIKE is pretty slow). Do you have any leading spaces sneaking in there?

Comment: +1 Wayne. Try this: WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST ('value')

Comment: If you are using UTF-8 collation you could need to force the string to to UTF-8 (would be treated as ASCII otherwise, causing LIKE to fail) You could do it this way: `N'%value%'`

Comment: @WayneWhitty I have fulltext search also..and I don't why it is also not give me any resulting..

Comment: @Kickstart no there are no leading spaces I have checked that also..

Comment: you know guys I try if Like is not working because of case sensitivity and I got the results when I try LIKE 'San%'...

Comment: Can you put out the full SQL that is failing to work?

Comment: @Kickstart I have added my full..have look..

Comment: Afraid I can't see anything wrong with your syntax at all. Sorry.

Comment: @Kickstart yes it was not giving me any error but it was not getting result that I was expecting..anyway I got it working and query is written as answer..thanks for your help..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try `name LIKE '%value'`?

Comment: He asks to filter on names beginning by "value" and not finishing by "value

Answer (score 0):

I don't why LIKE is behaving case sensitive but below modification worked for me.

```
SELECT z.zone_id, CONCAT( z.name,  ',', c.name ) AS zone FROM zone z
LEFT JOIN country c ON z.country_id = c.country_id
WHERE LOWER( z.name ) LIKE  'san%'
```

Above query gave me perfect result. Thank you all for helping.